# Fastest & easiest way to build existing VS2019 .NET 5.0 Windows Forms app for Mac (e.g. Mono)?

Tags: macos, winforms, mono, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have a simple Solution in Visual Studio 2019 Community edition with a C# Class Library (.NET 5.0), a Windows Forms application (.NET 5.0), and a command line interface (also .NET 5.0). The Forms and CLI both reference the library. Everything works great on Windows at the moment. I would like to create Mac versions of the applications. I have some general awareness of Mono and that everything I have done so far should work fine in Mono and cross platform (eventually, some of this might also be used in a Unity app, but that's not a priority at the moment).

What is the quickest and simplest way to take my VS 2019 solution and build the Windows Forms and CLI for Mac? Ideally I'd like to do this from my Windows environment.

I have read a number of posts and done some googling, and started to go down a few rabbit holes, only to find out they are outdated etc., so I thought it best to ask here and get a fresh response.

Comment: There is no such thing as "WinForms on .NET 5 on macOS" now, and no "fresh" either, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea You only have a small range of options.

Comment: Which of those three is the problem? WinForms should work on macOS with Mono https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/ ... is the .NET 5.0 part the problem?

Comment: ok, so I see that Mono supports up to 4.7 (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) ... if I targeted 4.7 would there be an easier answer?

Comment: The Mono page has been out of date for years, so trusting that today only leads you to the wrong path. Read my blog post carefully as I already revealed why. .NET Core/.NET 5 only supports WinForms on Windows. Period.

Comment: Interesting post. I'm not seeing where it mentions .NET 5. From your post I see that WinForms has an implementation on Mono and some people have encountered bugs with it that, especially with third party controls, which I am not using. This is a super simple UI so I am not too worried about that.

Comment: Unless your browser has problems showing "Mono’s WinForms implementation on macOS uses some legacy interfaces and is 32 bit only. So when latest macOS no longer supports 32 bit applications, this approach is a dead end. There was an attempt to port Mono WinForms to 64 bit, but no further news on that."